# Create NSDate objects based on time zone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I get the following date format from my application.

```
07/18/2011/04/45/EDT
```

I sub-string that to "07/18/2011/04/45" and "EDT".

Using the following code I compose a date.

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy/HH/mm"];
   [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EDT"]];

   NSDate *currentServerDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:formattedDateString];
   NSLog(@"currentServerDate %@",currentServerDate);
```

However when I print the NSDate (created using above formattter) it print as "2011-07-18 14:15:00 +0530" where +0530 is my timezone. I need to compose the relative to the EDT timezone. How do I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Please show the code where you create the date and then print it.

Comment: OK updated the post with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the time zone is probably not what you think it is.  Try logging the time zone returned by [timeZoneWithAbbreviation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000190-CJGDIGFF) and seeing what it tells you.  Also, review the documentation I linked to where it says:

> In general, you are discouraged from using abbreviations except for unique instances such as “UTC” or “GMT”. Time Zone abbreviations are not standardized and so a given abbreviation may have multiple meanings—for example, “EST” refers to Eastern Time in both the United States and Australia

Comment: Thanks Jeremy seems like this is the issue. Vote up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default `NSDate`'s `description` method shows date in GTM with your system's locale offset. If you wish to pring `NSDate` using `NSLog` use one of following:

```
NSLog(@"date = %@", [date descriptionWithLocale:some_other_locale])
NSDateFormatter *formatter = ...
NSLog(@"date = %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```